# JQuery : Date Range Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, daterangepicker

How to identify whether user chosen from the predefined ranges in the dateRangePicker?

For e.g, I have 3 predefined options like

- Yesterday
- Last 10 days
- Last 30 days

If user choose from the above options or if user select some other time period, How can I differentiate ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
<script src="jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker.js"></script>
```

sample code :

```
<head>
<link href="jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() { $("#e1").daterangepicker(); });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <input id="e1" name="e1">
   </body>
```

Comment: My question is not how to use date range picker. How to differentiate the selected date range whether presets values or users chose?

Comment: You can compare the date selected by user with today's date to find out your predefined set of dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **apply.daterangepicker** event to get to know the selected option.

```
$('selector').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      console.log(picker.chosenLabel)
});
```

I know it's late but it may help others.

cheers